# How i can write it in a different way? (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
echo set x=%x% > file.bat
echo set y=%y% >> file.bat
echo set z=%z% >> file.bat
echo set a=%a% >> file.bat
echo set b=%b% >> file.bat
```

And i don't want write in this way because i must create spaces, when i write like this:

```
echo set x=%x%> file.bat
echo set y=%y%>> file.bat
echo set z=%z%>> file.bat
echo set a=%a%>> file.bat
echo set b=%b%>> file.bat
```

it doesnt saving all variables, please help!

Comment: does some of the variables contain digits?

Comment: Yes, they are, this is save maked in >> operators::
set Name=P1  
set Level=1  
set Class=Warrior  
set PDmg=30  
set PMaxHp=125  
set PAccuaracy=60  
set PD=51 
set Lifes=3  
set AD=15  
set AH=20  
set AC=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
echo set x=%x%
echo set y=%y%
echo set z=%z%
echo set a=%a%
echo set b=%b%
) > file.bat
```